# Setting a color based on theme

Tags: android

I have an accent color that I use through out my layouts.  I have it defined as a style that I apply to a TextView.

My application lets the user choose between a dark theme and a light theme. I would like to tweak the accent color based on the selected theme.

- You can't define a color in a theme
- You can't define a state list color based on theme
- You can't separate resources based on theme (as you can for version or screen size)
- You can't update the resource color from code (??? not 100% on this ???)

How should I control my accent color based on the selected theme?

The dev guide gives an example of a theme using a custom color, which is close to what I want.  I need to be able to change the color at runtime.  I know I could go into my code and the X places where this style is being used I could ferrit out the component and set the color that way.  But I would think I could accomplish this with some combination of style/theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved this was by creating subclasses of the android.widget.TextView.  I created a TextViewAccented and a TextViewWarning.  I use these TextViews in my XML where I want the accent or warning color.  I remove any color references from the XML.

The subclasses contain the three default constructors.  All three constructors call a private method called setColor().  setColor() then inspects the selected theme and can use the desired shade based on the currently selected theme.

It's a fairly clean mechanism, but it's hard to believe that I can't code this in a theme.  That seems exactly what a theme should be for.