# Support library for text color behaviour of API 26?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-color

API 26 introduces an advanced color calculation for `?textColorPrimary` based on `?colorForeground`. It makes use of states, `primaryContentAlpha` and `disabledAlpha`.

`sdk/platforms/android-26/data/res/color/text_color_primary.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:alpha="?attr/disabledAlpha"
        android:color="?attr/colorForeground"/>
    <item android:alpha="?attr/primaryContentAlpha"
        android:color="?attr/colorForeground"/>
</selector>
```

On API 23 it falls back to white text by means I failed to figure out.

Is there a support library I could apply to get the color calculation of API 26 for older devices?

Comment: it would be easier to find the other way around

Comment: The other way round? Isn't it the common way to add support libraries to  bring new features into older API?

Comment: The way it's been done until API 23 is that you'd have to provide a different text color selector for each of your themes. Since API 23 theme attributes in colors are supported (and backported). If you find no other alternative you can define your own attribute `primaryContentAlpha` and use it in your app.

Comment: Yes, defining my own attribute `primaryContentAlpha` works. Yet it requires to also define my own `color/text_color_primary.xml`. So after all I still have to define the text colours separately. Using `?colorForeground` as central, default color setting seems not to be a mature feature with respect to older devices.

Comment: None-the-less when working with multiple themes this handmade port-back solution is still interesting and useful. That's exactly my case of usage.

Answer (score 1):

@eugen-pechanec is hinting that the attributes `primaryContentAlpha` and `scondaryContentAlpha` are missing, IMHO below API 26. Should we call this a bug or a missing back port? Don't know.

The consequence is that you can't use the setting `?attr/colorForeground` as a default to automatically create all foreground colours out of the box. You basically have two options, either not to use it to to do a manual back port.

### Disable `colorForeground`

Instead of generating the colours from `?attr/colorForeground` you set the attributes `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary` directly. This will be the best choice in most cases.

### Backport `colorForeground`

If you plan to use a lot of different themes, you want to enable the feature to set defaults for all text colours in a central place. Then you have to implement the behaviour of API 26 in your root theme.

`root theme`:

```
    <!-- workaround to port back API 26+ behaviour -->

    <!-- below 26 these two attributes are missing in the android namespace -->
    <item name="primaryContentAlpha">1.0</item> 
    <item name="secondaryContentAlpha">.85</item>
    <!-- works below 26 -->
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">.4</item>
    <!-- use my own files to connect my custom attributes -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
```

`app/src/main/res/color/text_color_primary.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha" android:color="?android:attr/colorForeground" />
    <item android:alpha="?attr/primaryContentAlpha" android:color="?android:attr/colorForeground" />
</selector>
```

`app/src/main/res/color/text_color_secondary.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha" android:color="?android:colorForeground"/>
    <item android:alpha="?secondaryContentAlpha" android:color="?android:colorForeground"/>
</selector>
```